# Removing duplicate values in TEXTJOIN and IF function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using the TEXTJOIN function with IF:

It works fine, but also includes duplicate values.

```
{=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(C4:C9=E4,B4:B9,""))}
```

The result I get with this formula (see the image attached) is 1, 1, 3, 4, but I need it to show 1, 3, 4

[image]

How can I make it show only the unique values?

Comment: Would this work: `{=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(C4:C9=E4,IF(MATCH(B4:B9,B4:B9,0)=(ROW(C4:C9)-ROW(C3)),B4:B9,""),""))}`? Remember to enter it as an array formula.

Comment: @JvdV I was looking for a similar thing and your formula works., like where there is only 1 value for the, e.g. if there is only 1 C in Column C with a value in B

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Office 365, Try this

=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,UNIQUE(IF(C4:C9=E4,B4:B9,"")

Enter CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: Dynamic arrays in Excel 365 make Array formulas obsolete - your solution works even without Ctrl-Shift-Enter

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but enter with Ctrl+Shift+Enter:

=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(C4:C9=E4;MATCH(B4:B9;B4:B9;0)=(ROW(B4:B9)-ROW(B3));B4:B9;"");""))